# Trying to throw own exception

Tags: java, exception

I created my own throwable exception but when i want to throw it, the editor says, that a reference to an enclosing class required. I don't know, what i need to write.

Here's code:

```
public class Main {
    int i = 0;
    public Main() {
        if (i == 0) throw new MyException("i must not be 0"); //Here it says about enclosing class
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new Main();
    }
    public class MyException extends Exception {
        public MyException(String e) {
            super(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Someone can tell me, where and what i must write?

Comment: Probably least confusing to just move the MyException out of Main, to be a stand-alone class.  (Of course, javac will insist that you put it in its own .java file since it's public.)  Otherwise make it static.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've defined MyException as an inner class of Main, then created an instance of it with no corresponding instance of Main available (since the main method is a static method).

You need to declare the exception class separately, outside of Main. Changing the access from public to package-private would let you keep the declaration in the same file. Otherwise, since you can have only one public class per file, it would need to go in its own file.

Alternatively you can define this as a static inner class, like so:

```
public class Main {
    int i = 0;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        if (i == 0) throw new MyException("i must not be 0"); //Here it says about enclosing class
    }

    static class MyException extends Exception {
        public MyException(String e) {
            super(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Making the class static means it does not refer to an instance of the enclosing class.

Answer (score 1):

Either declare `MyException` class as `static`

```
public static class MyException extends Exception {
    public MyException(String e) {
        super(e);
    }
}
```

Or declare it in its own compilable `.java` file.

The way you have it now, `MyException` is an inner class of `Main` which requires an instance of `Main` to be initialized.

```
throw new Main().new MyException("i must not be 0");
```

After your edit, obviously everything works...

Answer (score 1):

This is a general problem: Your class `MyException` is a nested class to your `Main` class, and it will always hold a reference to its enclosing instance. You want to make that exception class `static`, too.

Alternatively, in general but probably not in this case, you can instantiate the inner class using an instance of the outer class:

```
Main m = new Main();
throw m.new MyException();
```

Yes, that’s a new after the dot.